# How to edit the ID of each button in a class if a condition is true in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, chart.js

I'm using ChartJS to generate a pie chart in that elements are added every time the user clicks a specific button (I have 14 buttons that trigger the adding of a specific element in the pie chart, each one triggers a function that adds info to 3 arrays as needed in order for the chart to work.

Every time the user clicks a button a new one is created in a div that contains all the elements that are present in the chart because I want them to be able edit or delete the elements as needed.

To know what which elements from my arrays is edited by which edit button I'm using a variable named btnctr that I initialized with 0 at the beginning of my JS file. That variable gives every new ”edit button” an ID and then  then increments, like this:

```
function CreateEditButton() {
var buttonnode= document.createElement('input');
buttonnode.setAttribute('type','button');
buttonnode.setAttribute('id',btnctr);
...
$("#rotationelements").append(buttonnode);
$("#rotationelements").append(' ');
btnctr++;
 };
```

My problem is that I also have to make deleting elements possible. I'm using splice for deleting elements from the arrays, but that also messes up the position of other elements and my edit buttons become useless.

I want to also edit the IDs of my buttons when I delete elements, because I need them to be in sync.

Here's what I've come with so far:

```
// Get editbuttons
var editbuttons = document.getElementsByClassName('editbtn');

// Delete element
function deleteElement (x) {
    names.splice(x,1);
    dataset.splice(x,1);
    colors.splice(x,1);
    chart1.update();
    time=time-length[x];
    length.splice(x,1);
    UpdateTime();
    var delbtn=$("#"+x);
    $(delbtn).remove();
    var newid=x;
    for (var i=0; i<editbuttons.length;i++) {
        if (editbuttons[i].id>x) {
            editbuttons[i].id=newid;
            newid++;
            btnctr=newid++;
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear how you bind the add element functionality and the delete element functionality to your buttons. If done correctly, you wouldn't need to change any ids at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lulian, inside of your for loop it looks like you are only changing the id's of editbtns after the one that was deleted above. You may want to try taking out the if statement and replacing "newid" with "i":

```
for (var i=0; i<editbuttons.length;i++) {
   // if (editbuttons[i].id>x) {
        editbuttons[i].id=i;
        //newid++;
        btnctr=i;
   // }
}
```

This way you can re-initialize all of you editbtn's and btnctr to match from beginning to end.

Comment: It looks like you're right - thank you! 

I played around with this function for a long time and that code was a leftover from my old attempts. I tried doing that without a for yesterday and that's why I tried changing only the IDs after the deleted button. It made sense to me yesterday, but now I know I was overthinking it.